# CSS rules not applied to elements appended from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've search through the similar questions but none answered my problem. (all those problems seemed related to typos)

I'm just making this for fun.  I'm creating a table using jquery based on json data. Problem is, the appended table rows don't inherit any of the CSS rules.  I feel like I've read about the cause for this before, specifically to tables, but the info eludes me.

**HTML:**

```
            <table width="100%" class="" id="mytable">
                <thead>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr><td>f</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>b</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>a</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**CSS:**

```
    tr:nth-child(even){background:blue}
    tr:nth-child(odd){background:green}
```

**JS:**

```
        // Build some test data
        var data = [];
        var cols = ['Col-A','Col-B','Col-C','Col-D'];
        for (i=0;i<10;i++){
            data.push(['A_'+i,'B_'+i,'C_'+i,'D_'+i]);
        }
        // data that would be sent to 
        var json = JSON.stringify({columns:cols, data:data});


        // build the table
        $('#mytable').tables(json);


    });


    // the magic function
    jQuery.fn.tables = function(json) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
        var head = this.find('thead');
        var bod  = this.find('tbody');

        // Build columns
        head.append('<tr>');
        for (i=0;i<obj.columns.length;i++){
            head.append('<th>'+obj.columns[i]+'</th>');

        }
        head.append('</tr>');

        // Add row data
        for (i=0;i<obj.data.length;i++){
            bod.append('<tr>');
            for(j=0;j<obj.data[i].length;j++){
                bod.append('<td>'+obj.data[i][j]+'</td>');
            }
            bod.append('</tr>');    
        }

        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code you don't append one full row at a time, but only fragments. What you'll expect to be rendered?

```
head.append('<tr>');
...
head.append('</tr>');
```

For this to work, your magic function should be something like this:

```
    // the magic function
    jQuery.fn.tables = function(json) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
        var head = this.find('thead');
        var bod  = this.find('tbody');



        // Build columns
        var row = '<tr>';
        for (i=0;i<obj.columns.length;i++){
            row += '<th>'+obj.columns[i]+'</th>';
        }
        row += '</tr>';

        head.append(row); // append the full row

        // Add row data
        row = '';
        for (i=0;i<obj.data.length;i++){
            row += '<tr>';
            for(j=0;j<obj.data[i].length;j++){
                row += '<td>'+obj.data[i][j]+'</td>';
            }
            row += '</tr>';
        }

        bod.append(row); // append the full row

        return this;
    }
```

Function which appends one full row at a time.

Comment: Gotcha. But I don't understand why it has to be a full row at a time.  It's the same data in the end being added so wouldn't it see the full rows then?

Comment: I don't know precisely why. I think if you open an html tag, you should also close it to be a full element appended.

Answer (score 0):

@Razvan hit the nail on the head, but I think there is a much more idiomatic way of doing this. After all, we are using jQuery, so we might as well be efficient.

```js
jQuery.fn.tables = function(json) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(json);
  var head = this.find('thead');
  var bod  = this.find('tbody');
  
  // Build columns
  head.append($('<tr>').append(obj.columns.map(e => $('<th>').text(e))));

  // Add row data
  obj.data.forEach(r => bod.append($('<tr>').append(r.map(e => $('<td>').text(e)))));

  return this;
}
    
// Build some test data
var data = [];
var cols = ['Col-A','Col-B','Col-C','Col-D'];
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    data.push(['A_'+i,'B_'+i,'C_'+i,'D_'+i]);
}
// data that would be sent to 
var json = JSON.stringify({columns:cols, data:data});


// build the table
$('#mytable').tables(json);
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even){background:blue}
tr:nth-child(odd){background:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" class="" id="mytable">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>f</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically, I use a couple chained-together arrow functions along with `.forEach` and `.map` to append the `<td>` and `<th>` elements to the respective rows and append the rows to the table in a single statement.

Comment: Of course @PhaelaxZ's function can be reduced or simplified. I've been focused however on a simple answer which clarifies the problem.

Comment: @RazvanTheodor That makes sense, and I upvoted your answer. I just thought that this would be worth mentioning just in case the OP didn't know the simpler way of doing it.

Comment: Add table row in jQuery 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery